# Cannot make UIPopover appear programmatically

Tags: uisplitviewcontroller, uipopovercontroller, ipad, uipopover

I want the pop-over to appear when the app is first launched in portrait mode instead of it being hidden and requiring the user to hit the button before the popover appears. I've tried to find solutions through the likes of Google and other StackOverflow threads, but I have not been able to figure it out.  So in the event the standard SplitView sample that is created by XCode is different I'll put the code below.  If I can make it work on this app I'm hoping that I can understand it and be able to apply it elsewhere.

I thought about trying to just call what is called when the button is pushed... but I can't figure out what is called and where it is declared...  I feel like I'm overlooking something basic and it's driving me bananas!

The DetailView Controller 
*DetailViewController.h*

```c
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController <UIPopoverControllerDelegate, UISplitViewControllerDelegate> {

UIPopoverController *popoverController;
UIToolbar *toolbar;

id detailItem;
UILabel *detailDescriptionLabel;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIToolbar *toolbar;

@property (nonatomic, retain) id detailItem;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *detailDescriptionLabel;

@end
```

*DetailViewController.m*

```c
#import "DetailViewController.h"
#import "RootViewController.h"


@interface DetailViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIPopoverController *popoverController;
- (void)configureView; 
@end



@implementation DetailViewController

@synthesize toolbar, popoverController, detailItem, detailDescriptionLabel;

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Managing the detail item

/*
 When setting the detail item, update the view and dismiss the popover controller if             it's showing.
 */
- (void)setDetailItem:(id)newDetailItem {
    if (detailItem != newDetailItem) {
        [detailItem release];
        detailItem = [newDetailItem retain];

        // Update the view.
        [self configureView];
    }

    if (self.popoverController != nil) {
        [self.popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    }        
}


- (void)configureView {
    // Update the user interface for the detail item.
    detailDescriptionLabel.text = [detailItem description];   
}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Split view support

- (void)splitViewController: (UISplitViewController*)svc willHideViewController:(UIViewController *)aViewController withBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem*)barButtonItem forPopoverController: (UIPopoverController*)pc {

barButtonItem.title = @"Root List";
NSMutableArray *items = [[toolbar items] mutableCopy];
[items insertObject:barButtonItem atIndex:0];
[toolbar setItems:items animated:YES];
[items release];
self.popoverController = pc;
}


// Called when the view is shown again in the split view, invalidating the button and popover controller.
- (void)splitViewController: (UISplitViewController*)svc willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)aViewController invalidatingBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem {

NSMutableArray *items = [[toolbar items] mutableCopy];
[items removeObjectAtIndex:0];
[toolbar setItems:items animated:YES];
[items release];
self.popoverController = nil;
}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Rotation support

// Ensure that the view controller supports rotation and that the split view can therefore show in both portrait and landscape.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
return YES;
}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark View lifecycle

/*
// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
}
*/

/*
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
}
*/
/*
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
 [super viewDidAppear:animated]; 
}
*/
/*
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}
*/
/*
- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}
*/

- (void)viewDidUnload {
// Release any retained subviews of the main view.
// e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
self.popoverController = nil;
}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Memory management

/*
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
// Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

// Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}
*/

- (void)dealloc {
[popoverController release];
[toolbar release];

[detailItem release];
[detailDescriptionLabel release];
[super dealloc];
}

@end
```

The rootview is a typical UITableViewController and is nothing special, but if for some reason you need that or the delegate (which is pretty boring minus loading the views) to help me figure out this problem I have no problems posting those also.  Again this is straight up what XCode generates when I tell it I want to create a split view for the iPad and I have not modified it.

Hopefully there is something very minor I'm overlooking and it will make me smack my head and say "I can't believe I missed that!" Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out!

I put

```
[self.popoverController presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:[[toolbar items] objectAtIndex:0] permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
```

in the ViewDidLoad method.  I knew it was something pretty simple!  It seems to work without any problems!